# Add fixed fee to woocommerce depending on what's chosen on ACF Fields

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, advanced-custom-fields

I have a custom field in ACF where I want to add a fixed fee to woocommerce checkout if the user select Office 1 and 00:00 - 07:00.

How can I make this work?

Comment: You need to provide some code samples, or hints at what you've already tried and tested. It's not clear what you're asking for here.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in this way.

```
add_action('woocommerce_cart_calculate_fees', 'packing_fee');

function packing_fee() {
     global $woocommerce;

     // Check your condition if true, add fee
      $woocommerce->cart->add_fee('Fee Name', AMOUNT);
}
```